# Iterating through a table column containing dollar amounts returns NaN when adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add up the dollar amounts in a column. Currently I'm iterating through the rows and when I console.log, it shows the amounts. The problem occurs when I try to add them.

Here's my current code:

```
   var total,curAmount;
   $('#carrier-details-table tbody tr > td:last-of-type').each(function() {

       if($(this).parent('tr').css('display')=='table-row'){
         curAmount = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',','').split('$')[1]);
         total += curAmount;
         console.log(curAmount);
       }

   });
```

Again, curAmount shows the right numbers, but when I `console.log(total)`, it shows NaN. I've also tried changing the`$(this).text()` to `$(this).html()` but still nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of how the last column is rendered. You should initialise your variables if you are planning to use `+=` on them else it will return NaN.

Comment: Did you mean to drop the comma altogether in

`$(this).text().replace(',','')`

On line 5?

Comment: `total` is `undefined` at first hence `undefined + 1 == NaN `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps you need to initialize the variable `total`  to  `0`  first:

```
var total = 0, curAmount;
```

Comment: WOW... are you kidding me! That did it!

Comment: perhaps some bonus points? How do i make it only two decimal places? I tried toFixed(2) but that ends up not adding up the numbers

Comment: @Damien Put `total = total.toFixed(2)` after the loop `$.each`.

Comment: `var pi = 3.141592653589793;`

`Math.round(pi * 100) / 100;`

Which isn't javascript specific

Comment: You rock dude. Thanks!

Comment: toFixed returns a string, thats why a `+` is appending it not adding. `parseFloat(curAmount.toFixed(2))` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

total is initialized as `undefined` at first hence `undefined + 1 == NaN;`
You can change that: `var total = 0,curAmount;`